# assembled jar won't find hbase-site.xml in the same folder

Tags: java, maven, hbase

I've found some useful Q&A here already, but the problem still stucks. I'm using the following plugins in my pom file:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
              <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>hbase-site.xml</exclude>
                    <exclude>log4j.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>myfinalname</finalName>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <archive>
                    <manifest><mainClass>com.company.MainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

as you can see, I exclude the properties files (that are located in src/main/resources), and also add the Class-Path: . to the manifest. But when initializing hbase it can't find my hbase-site.xml which is located in the same folder as the jar file.

when I remove the *excludes* everything is ok, but I need the files to not be within the resulting jar, making them editable for the user.

As this should work I'm wondering if this is a problem with HBase, maybe HBase is using a different Loader?

How do I get HBase to load the configuration from the file located in the same directory as the executing jar file?

**EDIT:**

I create the executable jar and when I run it with `java -jar`, and also put hbase-site.xml into the same folder as the jar is located, when initializing hbase, it doesn't read my configuration

Comment: Could you please explain further about `when initializing hbase it can't find my hbase-site.xml`. Is it done by using `mvn ...` or `java -jar my_aritifact.jar` or whatever?

Comment: i updated the question. i start it with java -jar, and hbase-site, located in the same folder as the jar, isn't read.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following workaround. starting the jar with the following script

```
java -cp .:/path/to/myapp.jar com.company.MainClass
```

makes it read the hbase-site.xml located in the same folder. (this is based on the answers provided for this question here: [How to include hbase-site.xml in the classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326308/how-to-include-hbase-site-xml-in-the-classpath)) but I'd prefer using the *default*

```
java -jar myapp.jar
```

command. If you know how to achieve this (making the maven assembled jar including the folder in the path), please let me know. in the meanwhile I'll just stick to this workaround.