# Relationship between different hbase-site.xml for a Cloudera install

Tags: configuration, hbase, cloudera

With a Cloudera install of HBase, I saw three places have config information :

1. `/etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml`,
2. `/usr/lib/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml`,
3. and `/var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/*-hbase-MASTER`

Which one exactly is in effect? Or maybe all of them do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all cases of hbase the `/etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml` file is always read. The `/usr/lib/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml` is a symlink to `/etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml` so it is the same file.

Lastly, anything in `/var/run/` is a runtime variable and in your case it is the Cloudera Manager Agent. The Manager Agents are responsible for the management console and logging amongst other tasks.

I hope that helps,
Pat

Comment: Accept to this answer. Though this is not as correct as I expected, it successfully pointed out the symlink relationship.

Answer (score 0):

The config file used is **/usr/lib/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml**.

Other files aren't symbolic links.

Since the same configuration information needs to be used for other processes like HMaster,RegionServer, /usr/lib/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml file is synced at different locations while initializing/preprocessing of these daemons. Hence it is advised to make any configuration changes in **/usr/lib/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml** file only.

Also you need to make the same changes to these file on all nodes in your cluster and restart the HBase daemons. 
I hope these answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Per my search and learning, HBase actually has two types of `hbase-site.xml` files, one for HMaster/RegionServer, and the other for client.

In Cloudera's distribution, the `hbase-site.xml` file in folder `/var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/*-hbase-MASTER` is the config used by the running HMaster process. Similar is for RegionServer.

Yet the `site.xml` file under `/usr/lib/hbase/conf/` and `/etc/hbase/conf/`, symlinked from one to the other (according to @apesa), is for client usage. If one starts HBase `shell` on an HMaster host or a RegionServer host, this client config file will be used so the `shell` application knows how to connect to the ZooKeeper quorum to obtain the running HBase service. If one wants to use the HBase service from a client host, then he needs to copy this client xml file to the client host.

For regular Apache installation of HBase, as was indicated in Sachin's answer, the same `hbase-site.xml` is used for both purposes, though the HMaster, the RegionServer, and the client processes will use only the options needed and ignore the rest.

Answer (score 0):

From experimenting with the `hbase` binary version `1.2.0-cdh5.16.1`, it appears to use the Java classpath to find the `hbase-site.xml` file to use, whether running as a server or a client shell. There is a configuration parameter (`--config`) you can pass to `hbase` to control the config directory used, which by default is `./conf` (run `hbase` to view the documented help on this).

This observation is supported by other answers on this topic (e.g. [Question 14327367](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14327367/323177)).

Therefore, to answer your specific question, to determine which config file is used on your machine, run `hbase classpath` and find which of the 3 directories appears first in the classpath.