# Not able to create hbase using java

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I have written a simple [java](/questions/tagged/java) code for creating a table in hbase but somehow it is not working. I checked that all services are working fie i.e. `HMaster`, `Regionserver` and `Zookeeper`. Below is a code that i wrote

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HColumnDescriptor;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin;
public class CreateSchema
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{

try
{
   HBaseConfiguration conf = new HBaseConfiguration(new Configuration());
   HBaseAdmin hbase = new HBaseAdmin(conf);
   HTableDescriptor desc = new HTableDescriptor("sample");
   HColumnDescriptor meta = new HColumnDescriptor("samplecolumn1".getBytes());
   HColumnDescriptor prefix = new HColumnDescriptor("samplecolumn2".getBytes());
   desc.addFamily(meta);
   desc.addFamily(prefix);
   System.out.println("Creating table");
   hbase.createTable(desc);
   System.out.println("Done");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    System.out.println("Error Ocuured");
    }

     }
    }
```

Here is a zookeeper log.

> 2015-01-15 07:46:01,594 - INFO 
>   [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServer``CnxnFactory@197]
>   - Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:60599 2015-01-15 07:46:01,595 - WARN 
>   [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:ZooKeeperServer@822] -
>   Connection request from old client /127.0.0.1:60599; will be dropped
>   if server is in r-o mode 2015-01-15 07:46:01,595 - INFO 
>   [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:ZooKeeperServer@868] -
>   Client attempting to establish new session at /127.0.0.1:60599
>   2015-01-15 07:46:01,619 - INFO  [SyncThread:0:ZooKeeperServer@617] -
>   Established session 0x14aec781bb9000b with negotiated timeout 40000
>   for client /127.0.0.1:60599 2015-01-15 07:46:37,151 - INFO 
>   [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@197] -
>   Accepted socket connection from /10.0.2.15:58102 2015-01-15
>   07:46:37,152 - WARN 
>   [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@357] - caught
>   end of stream exception EndOfStreamException: Unable to read
>   additional data from client sessionid 0x0, likely client has closed
>   socket
>           at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228)
>           at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 2015-01-15 07:46:37,153 - INFO 
>   [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1007] -
>   Closed socket connection for client /10.0.2.15:58102 (no session
>   established for client)

After running Hbase java programm nothing happens.

```
java CreateSchema

Creating table
```

Please let me know what could be the issue.

Comment: Can you check the log of your application? You would need to configure the logger if you haven't already done so.

Comment: Hi 
Are you referring to Hbase log (var/log/hbase). If yes then I checked this log but I could not find anything useful. 

The only error that I found was in zookeeper. 

Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x0, likely client has closed socket at 

Is there any way that I can use for testing connect between Hbase and zookeeper ?

Because when I tried to create Hbase table from Hbase shell , it worked perfectly.

Not sure why this is causing issue with Java.

Comment: No, I'm referring to the log of your own application. The one that's trying to connect to hbase. It's probably some configutration issue, and the log would tell you that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the reason this might occur is your `hbase-site.xml` is not available in the classpath.

When you run:

```
HBaseConfiguration conf = new HBaseConfiguration(new Configuration());
```

HbaseConfiguration based the hbase-site.xml is created.

PS: I ran your code as such in my eclipse and it worked fine. The table sample got created without any error.

Comment: adding conf folder to classpath https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326308/how-to-include-hbase-site-xml-in-the-classpath/14327367#14327367